# Language based sorting in ElasticSearch based on order mapped to language

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to sort the content in elastic search based on language.

Example Input :

{
  [
    "title": "title1",
    "language": "english",
    "weight": 12,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ][
    "title": "title2",
    "language": "hindi",
    "weight": 11,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ][
    "title": "title3",
    "language": "english",
    "weight": 13,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ][
    "title": "title4",
    "language": "telugu",
    "weight": 10,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ][
    "title": "title5",
    "language": "hindi",
    "weight": 9,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ][
    "title": "title6",
    "language": "english",
    "weight": 11,
    "startDate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
  ]
}

Now I need to order the documents based on weight field on top of that i need to have all the documents having (lauguage== english) first.

O/P will be --

english documents -- order by weight
all other documents - order by weight

Comment: There is no such thing as sorting in Elastic Search itself (well actually there is an unique id for any document but you can't use it to sort your documents in index). I can assume you simply want to receive documents in particular order when you execute a search request. Then you should read documentation about Search API and Aggregations: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ . If you are using Java API library, I think these things are described in it's documentation also.

Comment: Thanks, But still am not able tho get this requirement done. Can anyone please help me for this in any way not only like query elasticsearch. With some java logic but needs to have pagination also

Comment: how does your mapping look? can you share one sample document?

Comment: {
 [
  "title":"title1",
  "language":"english",
  "order":12,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
 ]
 [
  "title":"title2",
  "language":"hindi",
  "order":11,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
 ]
 [
  "title":"title3",
  "language":"english",
  "order":13,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
 ]
 [
  "title":"title4",
  "language":"telugu",
  "order":10,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
]
 [
  "title":"title5",
  "language":"hindi",
  "order":9,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
 ]
 [
  "title":"title6",
  "language":"english",
  "order":11,
  "startDate":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"]
}

Comment: I want to have that document to be sorted based on order and start date. Am having those two features, but now i need to get that document as first english content and then followed by hindi and telugu along with those order and start date.